# Conflicting Bootstrap and admin css in Django

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-admin

I'm using Bootstrap with Django, as well as css from the admin (for a date widget). My problem is that on the pages where I have the date widget, the admin css overrides the bootstrap css so the whole page looks different. How can I fix that?

base.html

```
<head>

     {% block extra_head %}
     {% endblock %}

    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

template with date widget

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load adminmedia %}

{% block extra_head %}

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/base.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/widgets.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/actions.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% admin_media_prefix %}{% endfilter %}";</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put bootstrap css inside `{% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}`. Don't worry as long as you didn't call `{{block.super}}`, bootstrap will not be activated.

```
<head>
     {% block extra_head %}
     <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
     {% endblock %}
</head>
```

To activate the bootsrap in other template, just simply put `{{block.super}}`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extra_head %}
    {{block.super}}
    //other css here
{% endblock %}
```

UPDATE:

To override the admin existing css. In your bootstrap css, you must put `!important` so that it will force your template to follow bootstrap design

Sample:

```
<p>This red text <strong style="color: red;">should be blue</strong></p>

<style>
   strong { color: blue !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: The bootstrap is activated, but the problem is that the admin css overrides the fonts etc. I want the bootstrap css to override the styles from the admin css.

Comment: you need to put `!important` in css boottstrap so that it will force it to follow bootstrap design